# FOSUserbundle Symfony2 add new filed one to many

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I ma trying to add a field, website (url), per user using Fosuserbundle

Here are my entities:

User.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="lcl_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_access_token;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $google_id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $google_access_token;


    //YOU CAN ADD MORE CODE HERE !
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Website", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $websites;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->websites = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add website
     *
     * @param Website $website
     * @return Branch
     */
    public function addWebsite(Website $website)
    {
        $this->websites[] = $website;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove website
     *
     * @param Website $websites
     */
    public function removeWebsite(Website $website)
    {
        $this->websites->removeElement($website);
    }

    /**
     * Get websites
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getWebsites()
    {
        return $this->websites;
    }

}
```

Website.php

```
<?
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="website")
 */
class Website
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $url;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="websites")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }
}
```

Than calling in the controller

```
.
.
.
     if($found===1)
          {
          $entity = new User();
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $website = new Website();
          $website->setUrl("http://www.google.com");
          $entity->addWebsite($website);

          $em->persist($entity);
          $em->flush();
          return $this->redirect('/scan');
          }else{
          return $this->redirect('/verifyurl');
          }
.
.
.
```

But somehow it doesnt get stored in the database.

Did I get it correctly?

New to Symfony2 and FOSUserbundle

**Update 1:**

Getting there ... had to correct it little bit (add Constructor etc)

Here is the code I have now:

User.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="lcl_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_access_token;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $google_id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $google_access_token;


    //YOU CAN ADD MORE CODE HERE !
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Website", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
    protected $websites;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->websites = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add website
     *
     * @param Website $website
     * @return Branch
     */
    public function addWebsite(Website $website)
    {
        $this->websites[] = $website;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove website
     *
     * @param Website $websites
     */
    public function removeWebsite(Website $website)
    {
        $this->websites->removeElement($website);
    }

    /**
     * Get websites
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getWebsites()
    {
        return $this->websites;
    }


    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $ir;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Website.php

```
<?
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="website")
 */
class Website
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $url;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="websites")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
 if($found===1)
      {
      $logger = $this->get('logger');
      $logger->info("found");

      $userid = $this->getUser()->getId();
      $logger = $this->get('logger');
      $logger->info("user".$userid); 
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($userid);
      $logger = $this->get('logger');
      $logger->info("user".$user);

      $website = new Website();
      $website->setUrl($gaurl);
      $user->addWebsite($website);
      $user->setId($userid);

      $em->persist($user);
      $em->flush();
      return $this->redirect('/scan');
      }else{
      return $this->redirect('/verifyurl');
      }
```

It works ... but only allows 1 entry per user ... by second entry I get an Exception.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Anybody and ideas how to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Website` entity is not being persisted in the code and neither on the relationship, therefore it's not being inserted to the database. You can change the relationship to add a persist cascade like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Website", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $websites;
```

By doing that, Doctrine will be able to persist any new `Website` entities found through the `User` relationship.

Comment: Thanks @Isouza Tried you solution. Can you look at my Update 1. It seems to work, but not fully ...

Answer (score 0):

This does what I wanted.

Had to store the website object and than the relation were stored in the database.

Maybe it helps somebody.....

User.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="lcl_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $facebook_access_token;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $google_id;
    /** @ORM\Column(name="google_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $google_access_token;


    //YOU CAN ADD MORE CODE HERE !
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Website", mappedBy="id",cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
    */
    protected $websites;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->websites = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add website
     *
     * @param Website $website
     * @return Branch
     */
    public function addWebsite(Website $website)
    {
        $this->websites[] = $website;

    }

    /**
     * Remove website
     *
     * @param Website $websites
     */
    public function removeWebsite(Website $website)
    {
        $this->websites->removeElement($website);
    }

    /**
     * Get websites
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getWebsites()
    {
        return $this->websites;
    }


}
```

Website.php

```
<?
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="website")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\WebsiteRepository")

 */
class Website
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $url;



    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="websites")
     */
    protected $user;


    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }


}
```

Controller:

```
if($found===1)
  {
  $logger = $this->get('logger');
  $logger->info("found");

  $userid = $this->getUser()->getId();
  $logger = $this->get('logger');
  $logger->info("user".$userid); 
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($userid);
  $logger = $this->get('logger');
  $logger->info("user".$user);

  $website = new Website();
  $website->setUrl($gaurl);

  $website->setUser($user);

  $em->persist($website);

  $em->flush();


  return $this->redirect('/scan');
  }else{
  return $this->redirect('/verifyurl');
  }
```